# Is it possible to add a close button to this IE6 upgrade warning?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer-6

I'm using this code to prevent users with IE6 from accessing the site.

http://code.google.com/p/ie6-upgrade-warning/

I'd like to give users the option to close the warning and continue to browse the site without upgrading their browser.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why not just build YOUR OWN warning?

Comment: So go into the code and add a close button to it.

Comment: Omg, that [code](http://ie6-upgrade-warning.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ie6/warning.js) is horrible. It creates dozens of global variables, and there is a lot of code repetition. It seems to have been written by a person with little understanding of how to write client-side scripts.

Comment: Diodeus- Time.
epascarello- How?
Sime- It works, that's what matters. Users don't notice global variables (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: You can replace that entire script with a single conditional comment.

Comment: It would be better to add chromeframe instead. https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the banner from Microsoft: http://www.ie6countdown.com/join-us.aspx You can add a close button with this code:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <div id="ie6banner" style='clear: both; height: 59px; padding:0 0 0 15px; position: relative;'> <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie/home?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode"><img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" height="42" width="820" alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today." /></a><a onClick="document.getElementById('ie6banner').style.display = 'none'; this.style.display = 'none';"</div> <![endif]-->
```

Comment: That works, but I don't want them to use IE8 either. I like giving them the option to choose Chrome, Safari, Opera, IE, or Firefox. But I'd also like to give them the option to continue browsing

Comment: If you're letting users 'continue browsing' with IE6/IE7, why have an 'update your browser' menu at all? You can make a `position:fixed` menu bar that stays at the top of the screen and can be closed.

Comment: It's for a B2B application where some users will not have permission to update their browser (because the company may centralize updates).

Comment: I just want to add a close function to the current solution- but I'm not sure how to.

Comment: Make a close button somewhere with `<a onClick="document.getElementById('IDOFTHEOVERLAY').style.display = 'none'; this.style.display = 'none';">Close</a>`